# jquery fadeOut complete got error: fadeOut(...).complete is not a function

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I am trying this:

```
var notifications = $( "#notifications" );
  notifications.fadeOut("slow")
  .complete(function () {
      alert('completed');
  });
```

But I got: **Uncaught TypeError: notifications.fadeOut(...).complete is not a function**

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two way to specify on-complete-callback:

By second parameter:

```
var notifications = $( "#notifications" );
notifications.fadeOut("slow", function () {
    alert('completed');
});
```

or by options:

```
var notifications = $( "#notifications" );
notifications.fadeOut({
    duration: "slow",
    complete: function () {
      alert('completed');
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this works. But I want to learn how can I add options?

Comment: I added options-way. Try it.